# How can I pass in a vale inside jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery I am finding some value as in

```
var myVal = "10" // this is dynamic
```

then using that in .css to add it as in

```
  $('#myID').css( 'left', 'calc(100% - myVal)')
```

However, I am certain there is a syntax error. Can someone please help me. How can I pas in myval in there?

Comment: use concatenation sign **+**

Comment: `$('#myID').css( 'left', 'calc(100% - ' + myVal + ')')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is to do the subtraction in the string, escape the string, *append* the JavaScript variable, and then close the string by appending '`px)`' afterwards:

```js
myVal = 10;
$('#myID').css('left', 'calc(100% - ' + myVal + 'px)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myID">test</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

$('#myID').css( 'left', 'calc(100%- '+myVal+' )' )